# Rhino Mock Stubbing method with ExpandoObject as parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub, expandoobject

I want to unit test that a method under test calls a stubbed object and method with the right parameters. The problem is that one of the parameters is a dynamic (ExpandoObject). If "data" (variable below) was a typed object it works as expected.

```
    ...
    [Test]
    public void MethodTest_WhenSomething_ExpectResult()
    {
      ...
      dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
      data.Id = param1;
      data.Name = param2;
      var myClass= MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyClass>();
      myClass.Stub(x => x.MyMethod("hello", data).Returns(expectedResult);
      ...
      var actualResult = anotherClass.MethodUnderTest(param1, param2);

      Assert.IsNotNull(actualResult);
    }
```

Any ideas how I can do this? BTW, I dont want to "IgnoreArguments" I am testing that right params are being passed in.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to define the stub which returns `expectedResult` when *the second parameter has the right values in the fields `Id` and `Name`*.

But now you stub is defined to return `expectedResult` when *the second parameter is the same as the `data` object*.

If so, then you just need to modify the `Stub` definition:

```
myClass
    .Stub(x => x.MyMethod(
            Arg<string>.Is.Equal("hello"),
            Arg<IDictionary<string, object>>.Matches(d => d["Id"].Equals(param1) && d["Name"].Equals(param2))
        ))
    .Return(expectedResult);
```